# How to access a mapped variable from aes() in geom_hline()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use the variable mapped to `y` in `geom_hline()`. Basically, I want to achieve the same behavior as in:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = qsec)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mtcars$qsec))
```

[image: mtcars plot]

But I don't want to "repeat" `mtcars$qsec` for the `yintercept` parameter.

I tried using something like `yintercept = mean({{ y }})` but this gives me the "Error: object 'y' not found". To be honest, I do not fully understand when we can use these curly brackets.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Based on your comment down below, I think you can try `stat_summary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_hline` does not have access to the `y` aesthetic. You could do:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = qsec)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(qsec)))
```

[image]

From the comments, it appears that the issue is having to repeat the code for several `geom_hline`s. One can actually pass several values to `geom_hline` in a single call, so the easiest way to do this might be to summarize the data being passed to a single `geom_hline` call:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = qsec)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(data = . %>% 
               reframe(mean = mean(qsec), 
                       sd = sd(qsec),
                       yintercept = seq(mean - 2*sd, mean + 2*sd, sd),
                       color = factor(c('-2sd', '-1sd', 'mean', '+1sd', '+2sd'),
                                      c('-2sd', '-1sd', 'mean', '+1sd', '+2sd'))
               ), aes(yintercept = yintercept, color = color)) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c('#FF000040', '#FF000080', 'red', 
                                      '#FF000080', '#FF000040'))
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaw, I suspected something like this, that's a bummer. The problem with this solution is that I still have to repeat the variable name in geom_hline's aes(). Thanks for clearing that up. Do you have an idea WHY geom_hline() does not have access to the y variable? I don't have any idea why it should behave that way.

Comment: @swolf it's because the `yintercept` isn't quite the same concept as the `y` aesthetic. There are ways round this where you could get the same output and avoid using the variable name a second time, but they are more convoluted. Is there a particular reason you need it that way?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Basically, I am plotting several hlines which all access the y variable (mean and several z*SD distances from the mean) and I wanted to save myself the repetitions of the y variable which is already mapped.

Comment: @swolf you can plot multiple hlines in a single call, so the way to do this would probably be to summarize your data and pass that to `geom_hline`. I'll add an example

Comment: Nice – that's still two repetitions for `qsec` but it is easily expandable to a lot of hlines without adding more repetitions. Thank you!